# About ListView in Window Form

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, custom-controls

I make a `ListView control` (with some column header) in my window form but when I run this code then it gives me error just like that

Line in my Form.cs file:

```
string packagename = 
    File.ReadAllText(Program.ProjectLocation + "\\" +
    Program.ProjectName + ".aProj");
```

> Error 'System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader'
>   does not contain a definition for
>   'ReadAllText' and no extension method
>   'ReadAllText' accepting a first
>   argument of type
>   'System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader'
>   could be found (are you missing a
>   using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

So please help me remove this error.

Comment: yeah,and did you write Using System.Io in you form.cs file?

Comment: You must accept correct questions by clicking on the tick symbol on right side of answer.If you wish other answer ur questions

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem could be this: did you call your listview or a column **File**?
If so, correct: `System.IO.File.ReadAllText(...);`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `File` refers to a variable of type `ColumnHeader` and not the `File` class in `System.IO`
What you need to do is right click the word file and choose "Go to Definition", most probably you will find something like `ColumnHeader File = new ColumnHeader();`

Answer (score -1):

Either 
`Program.ProjectLocation` OR

```
Program.ProjectName
```

is type of `System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader`, Add 
replace

```
Program.ProjectLocation.ToString()
Program.ProjectName.ToString()
```

I don't know which one is `System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader` so make changes according to that

EDIT ANSWER:

Either 
`Program.ProjectLocation` 
OR
`Program.ProjectName`
is type of `System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader`,

Reeplace it with
    `Program.ProjectLocation.ToString()
    Program.ProjectName.ToString()`

Reason: `ReadAllText("A valid file path as string");` But here you are trying to generate a file path by using column header so its throwing that error
I don't know which one is `System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader` so make changes according to that

Comment: the problem, as error states, is not inside `ReadAllText`, but that `File` (that probably is a ColumnHeader, a column of the ListView) has not `ReadAllText` method.

Comment: @Marco I didn't said ReadAllText is error I said error is in arguments passing to ReadAllText, that must be a valid string type. What should I do if Questioner is giving confusing variable names...

Comment: error says the the object that calls ReadAllText doesn't have this method!! So, because of File (class) has that method, this means IMHO that he's using an object called File that probably it's not System.IO.File but a ColumnHeader...

Comment: Not my mistake.. Ya I confused while reading the error. File(Class) has ReadAllText method too... I am not sure user584275
 is using File is as column name.